# Python looping list and append value to variable

Tags: python, list, loops, csv, indexing

I have a .csv file with IPs which I converted into a list with Python:

```
def ip_list():
    iplist = []
    with open("/path/to/file") as csvfile:
        csvlist = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for lists in csvlist:
            for item in lists:
                iplist.append(item)
    return iplist

ip = ip_list()

print(ip)

>>> ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", ...]
```

Now I want to have every value in the list and append them to a given parameter each time.

Function for context:

```
def gencontent(ip, value1, value2, time):
    content = [
            {
                "example": {
                    "ipadress": ip
                    }
            }
        ]
    return content

ip = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3"]

content = getcontent(ip[0-...], value1, value2, time)
```

I want loop content with each value in ip:

```
#Example list for reproduction
ip = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3"]

content = getcontent(ip[0-...], ...)
```

I do not want:

```
#Example list for reproduction
ip = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3"]

content1 = getcontent(ip[0], ...)
content2 = getcontent(ip[1], ...)
...
```

I want to loop content basically each time with a new ip value.

Thanks!

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: You havent encoutered for loops or list comprehension??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the getcontent() function does, but why not loop through the items in your list using a list comprehension?

```
content = [getcontent(x) for x in ip]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

can you be more specific about `content = getcontent(ip[0-...])`?

i don't know whether i get you.
maybe something like this?

```py
ip = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3"]
def getip(li):
    for item in li:
        yield(item)

ipgetter = getip(ip)


content = getcontent(next(ipgetter), value1, value2, time) # getcontent got "192.168.1.1"
content = getcontent(next(ipgetter), value1, value2, time) # getcontent got "192.168.1.2"
```

if loop is in an end, an StopIteration Exception will being raised

Comment: I have inserted an example function for more context.

Comment: hmm you want getcontent(ip, ..) to generate something like this? 
[
            {
                "example": {
                    "ipadress": ip1
                    }
            },            {
                "example": {
                    "ipadress": ip2
                    }
            }
        ]

Comment: No, basically I want the ip in "content = getcontent(ip[0-...], ...)" to be looped for each value in the list once the code is executed, up until every value in the llist is used. Kinda hard to explain. 
Dont want to append a new dict to the json :/

Comment: edit on my answer. don't know if this suit you... @zed

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out here :) I will take a breather and look through it again!

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to index them, maybe you could convert to a tuple and use `enumerate`.
For example:

```py
ip = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3"]

indexed_ip = enumerate(tuple(ip))
print(list(indexed_ip))
# OUTPUT: 
# [(0, '192.168.1.1'), (1, '192.168.1.2'), (2, '192.168.1.3')]
```

Or if you want the index to start at 1, instead of 0:

```py
ip = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3"]

indexed_ip = enumerate(tuple(ip), 1)
print(list(indexed_ip))
# OUTPUT: 
# [(1, '192.168.1.1'), (2, '192.168.1.2'), (3, '192.168.1.3')]
```

Alternatively, maybe a dictionary work for you in this situation.

Here’s an example using dictionary comprehension:

```py
ip_dict = { ip.index(ip_item): ip_item for ip_item in ip}
print(ip_dict)
# OUTPUT:
# {0: '192.168.1.1', 1: '192.168.1.2', 2: '192.168.1.3'}
```

You can name the keys for the dictionary, whatever you’d like. if you’re sent on `content0`, `content1`, etc, you could change the key value in the dict comprehension to something like  `f’content{str(ip.index(ip_item))}’`. Then you could get the value from the `ip_dict` using `ip_dict['content1']` and etc.